# Is it possible to dynamcally modify an event object? jQuery trigger() / bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it is possible to add properties to the event object that gets passed to the bind() event handler function. I have a piece of code that this bound to "mousedown". I would like to trigger this event explicitly. The problem is that the bind() handler expects some event properties that are provided when the mouse trigger the event; namely 'pageX' and 'pageY'.

I know that I can pass additional parameters as an array into Trigger() but I would prefer to not change the the bind() code. This may not be possible.

I'd like to trigger the handler below and 'fake' the pageX. Can that be done somehow?

```
 currentObj.bind("mousedown", function(e) {
                var handleElement = currentObj.find(".HwSliderHandle");
                var offsetMultiplier = calculateOffsetMultiplier();
                var newPosition = Math.round(e.pageX/offsetMultiplier) - sliderInfo.contextOffset.left;
                moveHandleTo(handleElement, newPosition);                    
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and then send it using the [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function :

```
var e = new jQuery.Event("mousedown");
e.pageX = 'fake value';
currentObj.trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
    $(document).ready(DocReady);

    function DocReady()
    {
        $("#test").bind("mousedown", mouseDown);
    }
    function mouseDown(e)
    {
       alert("X: " + e.pageX + ", Y: " + e.pageY);      
    }

    function fakeIt()
    {
       var e = { pageX: 40, pageY: 50 };
       mouseDown(e);
    }
```